# Taking multiple snapshots at the same time in Python on RPi

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, photo

I am currently trying to get a Raspberry Pi take 2 photos at the same time, using 2 web cams.
The setup is simple: 
1 x RPi mod B,
1 x powered USB hub,
2 x similar web cams (Microsoft Lifecam).

I am perfectly capable of taking a snapshot with any one webcam, but not both at the same time. I tried multithreading and multiprocessing without luck. If I do simple movements in front of the cameras (like counting seconds on my fingers), the 2 images show a different finger count.

[image: image from camera 1]      [image: image from camera 2]

Here is the multiprocessing trial code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import pygame, sys, time, math, socket
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame.camera


pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
# init camera
pygame.camera.init()
_imgres = (800,600)
_cam = []
_cam.append(pygame.camera.Camera('/dev/video0',_imgres, 'RGB'))
_cam.append(pygame.camera.Camera('/dev/video1',_imgres, 'RGB')) 

def snap(name,camID):
    info('function snap ' + str(camID))
    _cam[camID].start()
    time.sleep(2)
    _image = _cam[camID].get_image()
    _cam[camID].stop()
    pygame.image.save(_image, "image" + str(camID) + ".bmp")
    print 'snap done ', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=snap, args=('cam 0',0))
    p2 = Process(target=snap, args=('cam 1',1))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Multithreading trial code is similar.
What am I doing wrong ?

Thx for any help.

EDIT:
I have tried Jan Meisel's idea of starting 2 identical scripts from a third one. It is better but not quite there yet - see images.

[image: camera 1][image: camera 2]

Any other ideas ?
Thx

EDIT2: 
I have checked the timing between my threads, and changed a bit the coding. Now I am using a threading event to actually take the photos, while both threads are live and waiting for that signal. Timer 1 gives me from 0 to 1ms difference between the two 'start taking picture'. Timer 2 gives me from 160 to 230ms between the two 'finished'. I was able to set the exposure time to 250ms and the timer 2 read ... 260 ms. I guess this answers my problem: indeed, retrieving the bytes from the camera is a realtime process and cannot be split (thx to @duck for suggesting this) ; the lag is more or less dependent on the exposure time (or the amount of time the camera is 'capturing'). 
thx @jan for thinking along. I guess my next try will be on a dual-core...

Comment: I am not sure, but i think raspbeery pi is not a multicore processor so it can only handle 1 webcam at a time. Moreever since taking picture is a realtime process so the processor might be dedicated to it at the time when the picture is being taken , the saving part can be threaded. Thats why their is a lag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make one python script for webcam1.
Make another python script for webcam2.
Make a third script, that start the other scripts in separate threads.

If this doesn't work its a general pygame problem. Ask about your Problem on PygameMailingList.

Perhaps, the Pie can't handle to cams at the same moment.

Comment: Okay we need to find out what cause the delay. make a timer and check the delay between thread1 started and thread2 started. If the time between both is really short (< 5 ms) then it's a problem with the cam module or pie-processor. If the time between the 2 Threads is long (~ 200 ms) it's a python threading problem. In both cases you got an Problem!

Comment: If the problem caused by the processor. Try to overclock your Rasp! 1000 mhz should be possible! After that check the delay again.